# Get Values from a Spreadsheet Range using timed trigger with "Cannot convert [object Object] to (class)"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Running:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('…');
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet 1");
var values = sheet.getRange(2, 1, x, 3).getValues();
```

works fine in the Apps Script IDE/debugger, but when running on a timed trigger fails with `Cannot convert [object Object] to (class)` on the `var values…` line.

I can't think of a permissions issue related to triggers and spreadsheets that would be relevant here or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

dumb error, the error relates to the `x` variable used in the Range declaration.